# combine 2 sorted query with union

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm using union to combine 2 query.
there are some problem when i'm adding ORDER on it.

here's the query as it currently exists

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
       SELECT * 
         FROM (
              SELECT nama_barang
                FROM transaksi_jual 

               WHERE kategori_barang.`id_kategori`= "3"  
                 AND id_kampus = "1" 
                 AND (     nama_barang LIKE "%galaxy%" 
                       AND nama_barang LIKE "%young%" )
   ) A ORDER BY date DESC
       UNION 
       SELECT * 
         FROM (
               SELECT A
                 FROM nama_barang 

                WHERE kategori_barang.`id_kategori`= "3"  
                  AND id_kampus = "1" 
                  AND (    nama_barang LIKE "%galaxy%" 
                        OR nama_barang LIKE "%young%" 

                       )
              ) B ORDER BY tanggal DESC
       ) drived LIMIT 0,12
```

what is the problem with my query?
is that no other way to combine 2 sorted query into 1?
how to combine 2 sorted query into 1 ?

thanks, i appriciate your help. and sory for my bad grammar.

Comment: There are couple of very weird parts of code: `(     nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                       AND nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                       AND nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                       AND nama_barang LIKE "%%"
                      )` and `(    nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                        OR nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                        OR nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                        OR nama_barang LIKE "%%"
                       )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ORDER after a UNION, like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1

UNION

SELECT * FROM table2

ORDER BY id
```

This ORDER BY orders the whole result, from both table1 and table2

In case you want the records of the first subset first, try:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS order FROM table1

UNION

SELECT *, 2 AS order FROM table2

ORDER BY order, id
```

*Note: `UNION` is a lot heavier to execute than `UNION ALL`, make sure you need to remove double records when you want to use `UNION`.*

Comment: but how about ORDER BY order for each query. is that possible?

Comment: What would be the point? The whole resultset would be unorderd?

Comment: That said, I believe (not 100% sure) it is impossible yes, however there's a workaround (see my edit).

Comment: the point is to display the sorted by date data that contain all word from search key, and rest to display the sorted by date data that contain a few word from search key.

Comment: @user3209635 Ah ok, in that case I think the second code example would work for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i wonder, if union is alot havier than union all. then if i use there be data redundancy. how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `union` at all.  The two subqueries appear to be the same except for part of the `where` clause.

```
          SELECT nama_barang,
                 harga,
                 id_jual,
                 kampus.`nama`,
                 deskripsi,
                 tanggal,
                 baru 
            FROM transaksi_jual 
                 JOIN seller 
                      USING (id_seller)
                 JOIN kategori_barang 
                      USING (id_kategori)
                 JOIN kampus 
                      USING (id_kampus)
                 JOIN subkategori_barang2 
                      ON subkategori_barang2.`id` = transaksi_jual.`id_subkategori2`
                 JOIN subkategori_barang 
                      ON subkategori_barang.`id` = transaksi_jual.`id_subkategori1`
           WHERE kategori_barang.`id_kategori`= "3"  
             AND id_kampus = "1" 
             AND ((     nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                    AND nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                    AND nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                    AND nama_barang LIKE "%%"
                   ) OR
                   (    nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                     OR nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                     OR nama_barang LIKE "%%" 
                     OR nama_barang LIKE "%%"
                   )
                  )
           ORDER BY tanngal;
```

I'm not sure what order you want, but surely you can do it with one query.

EDIT:

I figured that is what you really wanted.  To do that, use the following `order by` on a single query:

```
order by ((nama_barang LIKE '%%') +
          (nama_barang LIKE '%%') +
          (nama_barang LIKE '%%') +
          (nama_barang LIKE '%%')
         ) desc
```

This will order by the number of matching keywords.  Note that I also changed the string delimited to a single quote.  It is a good idea to use single quotes for string and date constants -- and for nothing else.

Comment: This `LIKE` things don't confuse you at all?

Comment: @Alexander . . . I assume the OP has simplified the query for the question.

Comment: nope, that like things are build with 'for' looping, that separating each word from the search key that user input.

Comment: and, the point from my query is to display the sorted by date data that contain all word from search key, and rest to display the sorted by date data that contain a few word from search key.